# Avoid function overload explosion

Tags: typescript

Does TypeScript provide a way to avoid this sort of method overloading explosion and, in doing so, provide type safety to an unlimited number of varargs?

```
type Operator<FROM, TO> = (source: Stream<FROM>) => Stream<TO>

class Stream<V> {
    // ...

    pipe<A>(operator: Operator<VALUE, A>): Stream<A>
    pipe<A, B>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>): Stream<B>
    pipe<A, B, C>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>): Stream<C>
    pipe<A, B, C, D>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>): Stream<D>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>): Stream<E>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>, op6: Operator<E, F>): Stream<F>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>, op6: Operator<E, F>, op7: Operator<F, G>): Stream<G>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>, op6: Operator<E, F>, op7: Operator<F, G>, op8: Operator<G, H>): Stream<H>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>, op6: Operator<E, F>, op7: Operator<F, G>, op8: Operator<G, H>, op9: Operator<H, I>): Stream<I>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>, op6: Operator<E, F>, op7: Operator<F, G>, op8: Operator<G, H>, op9: Operator<H, I>, op10: Operator<I, J>): Stream<J>
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K>(op1: Operator<VALUE, A>, op2: Operator<A, B>, op3: Operator<B, C>, op4: Operator<C, D>, op5: Operator<D, E>, op6: Operator<E, F>, op7: Operator<F, G>, op8: Operator<G, H>, op9: Operator<H, I>, op10: Operator<I, J>, ...restOps: Operator<unknown, unknown>[]): Stream<K>

    pipe<TO_VALUE>(operator: Operator<VALUE, unknown>, ...restOperators: Operator<unknown, unknown>[]): Stream<TO_VALUE> {
        return restOperators.reduce((stream, operator) => operator(stream), this as Stream<unknown>) as Stream<TO_VALUE>
    }
}
```

Note that each `Operator`’s output type is the next `Operator`’s input type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's possible.**

Here is a working example which requires TypeScript 4 tuple types. The idea is to use an array generic `T` to keep track of each consecutive type to make sure the operators agree.

I based this answer off of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798119/#comment112816141_63798119) by @jcalz.

```
type Operator<FROM, TO> = (source: Stream<FROM>) => Stream<TO>

type Prev<T extends any[], K, D> = K extends keyof [ D, ...T ] ? [ D, ...T ][K] : never;
type Operators<VALUE, T extends any[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Operator<Prev<T, K, VALUE>, T[K]>
};
type PipeResult<T extends any[]> = T extends [ ...infer _, infer U ] ? Stream<U> : never;

class Stream<VALUE> {
    x?: VALUE; // Needed to make sure Stream<X> doesn't always extend Stream<Y>.

    pipe<T extends any[]>(...operators: Operators<VALUE, T>): PipeResult<T> {
        return operators.reduce<Stream<unknown>>((stream, operator) => operator(stream), this) as PipeResult<T>;
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
const OpA: Operator<number, 'hi'> = null as any;
const OpB: Operator<string, 'hello'> = null as any;
const OpC: Operator<string, Date> = null as any;

const OpD: Operator<1521, string> = null as any;
const OpE: Operator<5, 6> = null as any;
const OpF: Operator<6, 7> = null as any;


const NumberStream = new Stream<number>();

// x0: Stream<Date>
const x0 = NumberStream.pipe(OpA, OpB, OpC);
// x1: Stream<"hello">
const x1 = NumberStream.pipe(
    OpA, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB,
    OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB,
    OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB, OpB);

// Error on arg 3.
const x2 = NumberStream.pipe(OpA, OpC, OpC);
// Error on arg 1.
const x3 = NumberStream.pipe(OpD, OpE, OpF);
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYB7eAeAYgJRgWQBooAVGAPigF4oAKAZxQFd4BjCALigGVh4JEAtllx4yASioUefQelJkAUAtCQoABT4A3OVAgAPYBAB2AEzpRERkAG0AukQDSRACIVqD3QeNmoAawggKABmUNZQzkQAdNHEULZQAPyh4VExcdYO8ZxGEJoQ8ADcyuDQcPnIaHToAGoAggAyAKoAokSx+oam5pY2tm5QAN4KUCOhHgCWRn4BwSS2nGVIqBgauXKORHVNzWRtGX0KAL5FKtBq45DYEHSMADbAOh3e3VZ2-e1eXcnRkZNB+VAAPpEP4AxpxRLcXj8ISNCjZXL5IoKFi3RB0czSGE1BotChDUZQPQJThbFoFKAAekpUAAchAICZGVBUFABIh-FAbnwoTIhAANCgmFDXIwAcmAFluAHdECBzE9TLzsQBNMiRJSEsAXCCPT4+HpvGg-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)

---

Old bad answer: [**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYB7eAeAYgJRgWQBooAVGAPigF4oAKAZxQFd4BjCALigGVh4JEAtllx4yASioUefQelJkAUAtCRYCZGgDCAC0QBLAHZyoEAB7AIBgCZ01EJKgyIDIIs5BkA2gF0KlBVCBJCbmljZQnnYOaOiGAGb2UACCRPGJAEIU3gFBuQD8URoYKVCZOYGcxCEW1raRcPZFsQYJ8MmpLRlkRAB0fWlt2BB0wFDZuflQQyPVYbYN0U4ubi5e4xMbBTQA3lAADJwLRTr6RtPAFAC+nlVmNeHuUAV7UJwGEABu9t4Sd3NQAzU5Q2IIKcFmtUKjmarSgmg6sIAIooQaiJgV0hDwppgWi8U8oTESsjcfjcm9PvZSXiKV94NSJrSqaimfTyVB3nSANxKFgAG0QdFs0n4QgAakkADIAVQAohRtsCwHpIMY-pCaEdHCdDHIKOrwpzEgUjfAfK9CUtXFB3GsxGQaH0eih1I46JUxIdXVpdLriPrQpDAeCwWAsfNvRgJTLZQjEvICSLZAnWRbTTzcsrII6+i7Gm6vfmYowDABrAwoADuBiIJfLVYMds4SaEdYr1YVDL4wGYBigecWdB6fCsjDYNHovFFRAHRQklAos8ck5kAjERGA2j0tkF3CnsjbDfEGaClwUZ95KAMMzgSULi3QBkYAgARvYiAByLcfvwcxh8vkbR3FweRYK8bzAdJ7yaEZ4EMABzT9tAgACUB-Kg-wAoCbRAhQwOvUY4E0aDoVghCiERZAIF-J8sN3dweTw8DCLARESJiABGABWAAmDiiDIgx4Jo-9APo3D8Ig2V2IwLiiAANhEujgJAUDmLUTAZPQeSiAAdiUsSVMYpiCKgAA5Z833gFsMPeSs91XdALNfewHTERiAHoPKgUwDgc0V0EoixFEk0ZfIw5yrJbHoswgTUwBKOB0iIIj3JMmZTA4iLLPsaLYvixLIJSoq1GS0rirKpKKuq8raqquqSvqprGpayrWpq1LPO8gABYA6AAWjMSAWGAQb4HgNB0rCnjspc6z9wEGKVTi29ivhNRNDSryoF6gahogEaxom+lQp8gBmWaooWpbszgRFitjDS0qAA)