# Typescript reduce with changing accumulator type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a operator similar to [RXJS pipe](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe) that ingests a list of procedures and then processes them assembly-line style. However, Typescript is unable to check the dynamic typing of Reduce (the accumulator has a type based on the previous execution). Is there a proper way to do this?

```
const pipe = (...fns:Function[])=>{
   return fns.reduce((prevRes,curFn)=>curFn(prevRes),undefined)
}
pipe(
   ()=>true,
   (res:string)=>"res should be boolean, this should yell at you"
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63538630/2398020 is similar, may be useful

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAbgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBDXEAbQF0AaKAaToBEA+KAXgY2zyKgGsIIAPYAzKBQCuBCKICWuCPjoA6NaipQA-BOn5ZCpavVUK9TQC4oTANwBYAFABjYbkLAoYOZA5QAFH5qKqJuVgBi0k7Acq7UAJQcbCGEKgj4kk4QAWAIiABKEIR0TpJwYbgJ7GwlZbh+OUgFhHF0egaK+HEJJMRkIKSEjlBQaNw4BL3k1CyBaiRwAOaEVgDeEvRQCgJCYlAaVn6YVvBIaHSMUG3yHSyVbKhmmgC+d0PDe2O8xBRBCqIQcCgAH06H8AVAAKqaHQQqBWRSIAH2ZyudxQRAkAA2vi8kD8bz8dygwDgkggNAJCGWUAARsJhJiIGQiVTtFAAIwAJgAzHCoAAWACsADYKQ44siXG4PDSSPgcd4sgSiSSyWLhn4qVZ3HAFAsWYUoAB6I0YOBwYRwACEjjijilaPpYGInFxSocGqJACIABYQTGY4ReuiYRJQTAqRm4BbAH22mzG019K0poA) suffice?

Comment: One problem is that you'll find it hard to get the compiler to infer the callbacks' argument type, even though it should be obvious.  It's not a natural constraint in TS, unfortunately.

Comment: I have to admit, your playground is difficult for me to follow, but it seems to be the best we can do with this approach. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jcalz That's some really spectacular code, you should make it an answer

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose [I rearranged jcalz's code for myself, may be more readable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAbgHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcoBDXEAbQF0AaKAaToBEA+KAXgY2zyKgGsIIAPYAzKBSZ0AdLNRUoAfglSos6fIr0FALii4kEOAG4AsACgLoSFAD6MAJaQYJOCQC2hNNxwFiZSio2TgBvCXooB1wBITEoeT0AClcAcz14JDQ6RigAVwIIUSiIfBYASg42VC0FAF8zc2toeycIACUIQlyAG2BvLF8+AOpg+J9eYgo1WSjRIzs6WfmAVSgFZVW9A0QjBotRfIBjYAdhaLBW-p4-UnIRxPVRXEI9FudXDy9UctfHSA6ur00GwQhYoFAEMBcnBok9CNIEPhcocIMh8vxcMIAO64FiJRJgBCIAF0Q7QgBiuAq7DYZLglIJRIBZTo+XwhWK+AqJGIb3anR6fW+DVqFiAA)

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer, but I bet the list of overloads will actually behave better in many cases, especially with inference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can represent the constraint you want with [variadic tuples](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), but it has some unfortunate side effects on type inference.  If you're willing to explicitly annotate all of the callbacks' arguments, great.  If you're expecting the compiler to infer those for you, I'm afraid that you'll probably not do better than a big list of overloads for each possible number of functions, as shown in the other answer.

Anyway, let's introduce these helpers:

```
type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer _, infer U] ? U : never;

type Prev<T extends any[], K extends keyof T, D> = 
  K extends keyof [D, ...T] ? [D, ...T][K] : never;
```

The `Last<T>` type takes a tuple type `T` and returns its last element (so `Last<["a","b","c"]>` should be `"c"`).  And the `Prev<T, K, D>` takes a tuple type `T` and a (intended to be numeric) key type `K`, and returns the element at element "`K`-1", returning `D` if you pass in `0` for `K` (so, `Prev<["a","b","c"],1,"d">` should be `"a"`, while `Prev<["a","b","c",0,"d"]>` should be `"d"`).

You can use these to represent a type corresponding to a chain of functions:

```
const pipe = <T extends any[]>(
  ...fns: { [K in keyof T]: (arg: Prev<T, K, undefined>) => T[K] }
) => fns.reduce((prevRes, curFn) => curFn(prevRes), undefined) as Last<T>
```

We want `pipe()` to be generic in the tuple `T` which corresponds to the ordered list of return types for the functions passed in as `fns`.  The type `{[K in keyof T]: (arg: Prev<T, K, undefined> => T[K]}` is that chain of function type we need; for each index `K` in `T`, the resulting function's input type is the element at the previous index, or `undefined` if there is no previous index (`Prev<T, K, undefined>`), while the output type is the current element of `T` (`T[K]`).  And the output of `pipe()` is just `Last<T>`, the last element in the tuple of return types.

Let's see how it works.  The good:

```
const good = pipe(
  () => true,
  (res: boolean) => res ? 123 : 456,
);
// const good: 123 | 456
```

This compiles with no error, and `val` is inferred to be of type `123 | 456`.  And the bad:

```
const bad = pipe(
  () => true,
  (res: string) => res // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'
)
```

This is exactly the error you want; the compiler expects `res` to be of type `boolean`, but you've annotated it as `string`.  And now for the ugly:

```
const ugly = pipe(
  () => "hello", x => x.length
); // any!!!
```

Oops, I forgot to annotate `x` in the callback. Instead of being able to contextually type `x` from the return type of `() => "hello"`, the compiler gives up and implicitly uses `any`.  And this causes the entire tuple type `T` to be inferred as `any[]`, and all type safety is lost. This failure is likely due to the circular nature of the required inference; the tuple type `T` is dependent on the types of the callbacks, which themselves depend on the type of `T`.  It would be great if this worked magically, but it doesn't.

In any case, though, you can represent the constraint, and it might even be useful.  Just be careful of the pitfalls in inference.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCpQgD2BAdgEwSjlxAG0BdAPigF4p0scCiyA6DgS1wDMIAnKAH0ANFG59BAVQpQA-FClQAXFFwQAbgIDcAKFCQoABX6a0GbHkLFSlMQGkLzawGsIIAPY8GYgCI16RyYrIjdPbzJfMQ42VFkFSOiOOLJ7WVV1LX49XQBjD1wkKDBOQ3pzYJYbcmoAChieQtUAbyhU8VwoMK8GClVauH4Ac1UTM1QHMQBXAggebgh8KgBKOhpUVNkAX1XaKl0oKEaENlN8KdyIWtqwUw0AJQgEMVyp-gAxXF2aV4-cG7ujwQy2ms3m6nwq0QsEQKFQ+zyBSKQw8HnwdGKpSuUAOUFq3ygwH4UwgIlxtVMCFUACNUQAbCAkAmU+RQACMACYAMwqKAAFgArAA2MnLPQAenFUHyhWAUBRaNUnJ5AB9+cLdJqZUVqXB0fQSpBauSCUSSWTDhSnqokPxuENmU8oJKMPx+B5+ABCXGSgB+-oDgaDQZ94tQ4GgAHJaR4GSRI+IiLgPHLEAhOENcHBqQzCR5CRGoJHbfbI7plprEbKoFMhnSQBjDVcTWsoAAiAAWEDpdI8bbEmFbmDYDNwQ2AHfL2mdUpIIE9C90QA)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RxJS's implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/pipe.ts) for the pipe function.

```
export interface UnaryFunction<T, R> { (source: T): R; }

export function pipe<T>(): UnaryFunction<T, T>;
export function pipe<T, A>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>): UnaryFunction<T, A>;
export function pipe<T, A, B>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>): UnaryFunction<T, B>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>): UnaryFunction<T, C>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>): UnaryFunction<T, D>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>): UnaryFunction<T, E>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>): UnaryFunction<T, F>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>): UnaryFunction<T, G>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>, fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>): UnaryFunction<T, H>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>, fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>, fn9: UnaryFunction<H, I>): UnaryFunction<T, I>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>, fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>, fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>, fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>, fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>, fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>, fn9: UnaryFunction<H, I>, ...fns: UnaryFunction<any, any>[]): UnaryFunction<T, {}>;
```

To get type inference to work for the operators, they have to define a bunch of overloaded function signatures with generic placeholders for the operator signatures to fill in. Depending on how many operators are passed to the pipe function determines which overload is used, up to a maximum of nine, beyond which it falls back to `any`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pipe-type?file=index.ts) I've made a simplified example you can play around with using your code.

It's not the most elegant use of Typescript, but it's acceptable, given that it's not probably not very common to need so many operators in a single pipe. If you do need more, you can just chain another call to `pipe`.

Fortunately, Typescript 4.0, which was just recently released, greatly improves support for [Variadic Tuple Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) and inference, which may provide a much better solution that doesn't need a bunch of function signature overloads. RxJS maintainers [already have it](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5599) on their roadmap.

Comment: Thank you! I flipped a mental coin and accepted jcalz's answer, but yours is great too.